# Help solving a Fourier Series for a function with P=2L

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

I have a periodic function
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} -2x-x^2, & -2 \leq x < 0 \\ 
    2x-x^2, & 0 \leq x < 2 \\
f(x)=f(x+4) & otherwise \end{cases}$$
and this period is repeated. I have been trying to find the Fourier series for $a_{n}$ and as $f$ is even I don't need to find $b_{n}$. I also know the function has a period of 2 so I have been using $L=1$.

Then using the formula $\displaystyle a_n = \frac{2}{L} \int^{L}_{0} (2x-x^{2})\cos(n \pi x) \, dx $ with $L=1$, I get $a_n = \dfrac{-4}{n^{2} \pi^{2}}$ but I am not sure this is right, as I tried to integrate from $-L$ to $L$ and multiplied by $\dfrac{1}{L}$ instead of $\dfrac{2}{L}$ and got a different answer.

So am I right in having:
$\displaystyle f(x)= \frac{2}{3} + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \left(\frac{-4}{n^{2}\pi^{2}}\cos(n \pi x)\right)$ as my final answer?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I got your value for $a_n$. But i believe $L$ should equal $2$. If you do your other integral it should then be consistent.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 i get the period as 2 when i plot it on maple so i thought L=1?

Comment: i was interpreting it as an (periodic w period $2$) even extension of $(2x-x^2)$ on $[0,2)$. Then $L$ is the length of the interval. Idk its been a bit since i Did fourier series. But it checked out w my books formulas.

Comment: The Fourier series is indeed $$\frac{2}{3}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum_{n=1}^K -\frac{4}{n^2 \pi^2}\, \cos(\pi n x)\right)\tag{1}$$ which is equivalent to $$\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{\pi^2}\, \left(\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-i \pi x}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(e^{i \pi x}\right)\right)\tag{2}$$ where $\text{Li}_n(z)$ is the [polylogarithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html).